# do-release-upgrade to 13.04 crashed

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I did a do-release-upgrade to upgrade from my 12.10 to 13.04 Ubuntu. The download for 680 MB files were completed successfully. After 10-15 minutes of running, I noticed that the desktop windows got slow,alt tab,switch workspace etc weren't responding. I could open the terminal but no icons to close,minimize and restore. I still let it run for another 6 hours and final with no change I rebooted the system. 
On reboot it did show Ubuntu 13.04 but all the mentioned problems still persist and it also shows that compiz crashed during installation.

Now how do I  run the OS upgrade files again without downloading them. It seem Ubuntu is convinced that the OS upgrade has completed but then I am not sure if it is only the compiz or there are other files also that did not get installed because of this.
EDIT:
So as advised I ran the update-manager-text from terminal but still some errors. Also after running `sudo dkpg --configure -a` the above problems still persist.

```
sudo update-manager-text  [sudo] password for ajay:  
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... 
Done Building data structures... 
Done  Building Updates List Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/bin/update-manager-text", line 70, in <module> app = pdateManagerText(data_dir)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManagerText/UpdateManagerText.py", line 55, in __init__self.fillstore()   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManagerText/UpdateManagerText.py", line 90, in fillstore
self.list.pkgs, key=operator.attrgetter("importance"), AttributeError: 
'UpdateList' object has no attribute 'pkgs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please do not use `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade Ubuntu**. It tends to break the system. Please use the Update Manager:

1. Press the super key (Windows key) to open the Dash, type Update Manager.
2. Hit the **Check** button then **Install Updates**, repeat the process **until no updates is pending**.
3. Press now the **Upgrade** button.

   [image]
4. You will be alerted with the releases notes, Hit upgrade again.
5. Follow the in-screens instructions.

I believe you have problems of dependencies and whatnot, is such cases run `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix such issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the superkey also do not work.

Comment: If you have access to the console you could also type `update-manager-text`.

Comment: Unfortunately it says it is not installed and when I do a sudo install it says dkpg manager error. It prompts for running sudo configure --a to be run manually. Is that safe

Comment: When the system ask you to run `sudo dpkg-configure -a` *(I believe it's like this)* it means that could not configure all the packages on a previous installation, and by all means you can run such command as it's 100% safe, if it fails again, please edit your question and add the new information.