# update-manager-text fails with error: AttributeError: 'UpdateList' object has no attribute 'pkgs'

Tags: apt, upgrade, 17.10, update-manager

Running `update-manager-text` results in error message:

```
AttributeError: 'UpdateList' object has no attribute 'pkgs'
```

Here is the whole console output:

```
$ sudo update-manager-text

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building Updates List
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager-text", line 70, in <module>
    app = UpdateManagerText(data_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManagerText/UpdateManagerText.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.fillstore()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManagerText/UpdateManagerText.py", line 90, in fillstore
    self.list.pkgs, key=operator.attrgetter("importance"),
AttributeError: 'UpdateList' object has no attribute 'pkgs'
```

This is on Ubuntu 17.10 'artful'.

Any ideas?

Comment: checking site https://askubuntu.com/questions/328072/do-release-upgrade-to-13-04-crashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug. I can confirm it on my 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS.

This [bug 1385524](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1385524) has long history - since 13.10.

Comment: This bug was fixed in the package update-manager - 1:18.04.5

---------------
update-manager (1:18.04.5) bionic; urgency=medium

  * Drop the update-manager-text package and code as it has been broken for a
    long time and it wasn't used by many people. (LP: #1385524)